Tags: singular or plural?
I just had a look at the Tag list, and found both password and passwords. Obviously we don't need both.
A similar point would be hash and hash-functions.
There also are modes, s-boxes, resources, keys, timing-attacks, side-channel-attacks, elliptic-curves without a corresponding singular form.
All other now existing tags are in singular form.
I suppose in some cases the plural is preferable, in other ones the singular.
Could we find a rule on when tags should be singular and when plural?

While there's no hard-and-fast rule across the SE network, there's an overall trend towards tags using the plural version.
Consequently, I've made password a synonym of passwords (after merging them).
If there's any other tags that need tweaks, I'm happy to help.

After a bit of discussion in the chat, I just changed the last 3 occurrences of [tag:hash-functions] to [tag:hash] (if it was not already there). Could you either remove the first one or make it an alias?

Also [tag:gpg] and [tag:gnupg] should be synonyms (both are only on one (the same) question, which is already closed as off-topic, but maybe there could be new on-topic questions later). I'm not sure which one should be the main one.

I think, [tag:digest] should be a synonym for hash, too. (It is only on one question, which also has the [tag:hash] tag.)

Thanks! Should I add a separate question for these points?
